# Dependency problem on ubuntu 15.04 for ROS Jade

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am facing a problem while following the ROS installation procedure from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu). When I reach the step 1.4 and type :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-desktop-full
```

I'll get this error :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-jade-desktop-full : Depends: ros-jade-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The purple part in the tutorial is supposed to help with dependency issues but it is not related to 15.04 and they didn't help me anyway.
Needless to say, it is also not possible to only install  ros-jade-simulators or ros-jade-desktop-base

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218265/dependency-problem-on-ubuntu-15.04-for-ros-jade/) by [atabak](https://answers.ros.org/users/24052/atabak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-09-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the error I assume you've already installed Gazebo, of which version is not supported in ROS Jade (that supports version 5.x).

If and only if you're NOT using other versions of Gazebo than 5.x, you can simply uninstall those versions of Gazebo, which will also uninstall related ROS packages too so that `ros-jade-simulator` will become installable.

If you want to use specific version of Gazebo with Indigo or Jade, Gazebo team provided [an official way to install and use Gazebo5 or 6 with ROS Indigo](http://answers.ros.org/question/191475/how-to-make-ros-indigo-work-with-gazebo-4/?answer=218295#post-id-218295). With this way, however, you need to specify the wrapper packages in the dependency in your `package.xml`.

This is not a complete answer to any possible situations, but HTH.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atabak](https://answers.ros.org/users/24052/atabak/) on 2015-09-27**:
I am currently using Gazebo 6. Thanks for answer